# Accessing elements of a list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings, and calling  a function on each string which returns a string. The thing I want is to update the string in the list. How can I do that?

```
for i in list:
     func(i)
```

The function func() returns a string. i want to update the list with this string. How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to update your list in place (not create a new list to replace it), you'll need to get indexes that corresponds to each item you get from your loop. The easiest way to do that is to use the built-in `enumerate` function:

```
for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    lst[index] = func(item)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reconstruct the list with list comprehension like this

```
list_of_strings = [func(str_obj) for str_obj in list_of_strings]
```

Or, you can use the builtin [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function like this

```
list_of_strings = map(func, list_of_strings)
```

**Note :** If you are using Python 3.x, then you need to convert the `map` object to a list, explicitly, like this

```
list_of_strings = list(map(func, list_of_strings))
```

**Note 1:** You don't have to worry about the old list and its memory. When you make the variable `list_of_strings` refer a new list by assigning to it, the reference count of the old list reduces by 1. And when the reference count drops to 0, it will be automatically garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't call your lists `list` (that's the built-in list constructor).

The most Pythonic way of doing what you want is a list comprehension:

```
lst = [func(i) for i in lst]
```

or you can create a new list:

```
lst2 = []
for i in lst:
    lst2.append(func(i))
```

and you can even mutate the list in place

```
for n, i in enumerate(lst):
    lst[n] = func(i)
```

Note: most programmers will be confused by calling the list item `i` in the loop above since `i` is normally used as a loop index counter, I'm just using it here for consistency.

You should get used to the first version though, it's much easier to understand when you come back to the code six months from now.

Later you might also want to use a generator...

```
g = (func(i) for i in lst)
lst = list(g)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to do that.

```
map(func, list)
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3, `map` returns an iterator, not a list. If you need an actual list, you'd need to call `list(map(func, lst))` (this is an example of why `list` is a poor variable name).